# Manage aar dependencies in my aar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aar

We ship an aar to our customer(say A). Now our code uses a 3rd party AAR (say B). Now when we use this 3rd party AAR we add a compile dependency in our AAR's gradle.

```
compile 'B@aar'
```

The problem is that our customer wont have B.aar in their repo and we cant explicitly provide them a 3rd party AAR. How can I bundle B as a dependency in my aar?

Comment: "we cant explicitly provide them a 3rd party AAR" -- why not? If the answer is "their license forbids it", then their license probably also forbids you distributing their library embedded in yours.

Comment: Providing the customer a single aar looks much neater than providing them two more aar's apart from our product and asking them to integrate those two as well. Also it is not an acceptable solution to our product management. So in short I agree to your point, but if we had to implement the use case that I am talking about, is there a way to do it?

Comment: "Also it is not an acceptable solution to our product management" -- so, product management wants to make it difficult for your customers to maintain their apps (e.g., use a newer version of the third-party library that addresses a security flaw, deal with conflicts if they also want to use the third-party library directly for their own purposes). There is nothing in the Android SDK tools for creating a "fat AAR", in part because going that route is not recommended.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info. Just one more point, in our case we pay for the 3rd party aar's, so all updates will go through us and the customer will have no control over updates for that library. We will take care of that.

Comment: "so all updates will go through us and the customer will have no control over updates for that library" -- unless they also license it from the third-party, presumably. You're welcome to hunt around, as I think there are third-party tools for creating a "fat AAR", but YMMV.

Comment: We had been using https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar for the previous releases, but it doesnt work post updating gradle.